# Underlying connection closed error in WCF client

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf, connection

I was trying to create a WCF service which returns `IEnumarable<fVehicleTypes>`.

My service is

```
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(VehicleMaster))]
public IEnumerable<VehicleMaster> ListAllVehicle()
{
   IEnumerable<VehicleMaster> vehicles = veadb.VehicleMasters.OrderBy(v=>v.ID).Select(v => v);

   return vehicles.ToList();
}
```

And client I am trying to

```
public ActionResult ListAllVehicles()
{
            VEACRUDE.VEACRUDClient veadb = new VEACRUDE.VEACRUDClient();
            var VehicleDetails =veadb.ListAllVehicle();

            veadb.Close();
            return View(VehicleDetails);
}
```

This is where it is throwing the above mentioned error. I tried all I could find over internet. Nothing helped.

Also I tried enabling tracing, which didn't work at all.

Comment: I can't find service and operation contracts in your code. Did you already had it?

Answer (score 1):

WCF is a message-based system using XML-serialized messages to communicate between client and server. This means that WCF messages have to be in such a way that they can be expressed in a **XML schema** and thus packaged up into a XML message.

WCF is **not** a remote procedure call system, e.g. there is no "live" connection at runtime between the client calling the server - the client just send a request as an XML message to the server, and the server responds by sending back another XML message containing the response.

This also means: you can **only** use explicit **concrete types** - no interfaces. And it also means: no generics. So `IEnumerable<VehicleTypes>` is not good for two reasons: generics and interfaces.

You will need to create a `VehicleCollection` type on your server-side, and use that to package up the list of vehicles you want to send back. Mark it as a `[DataContract]` and mark all its members that you want to have serialized as `[DataMember]`

Comment: Could you please show that with my code?I mean can you modify it accordingly?I am a bit confuse about this.I read somewhere we can use Ienumarable and no need of serialization to be done?